# Correction of variables for Age and Gender

Tags: t-test, normalization

I have a table of variables (levels of different chemicals in the blood) for 2 groups of patients -- healthy and sick. I would like to find variables significantly different in those 2 groups. I can do t-test, but it does not account that the patients are of different age and gender, which can also affect the chemical content of the blood. Gender is binomial so we can do t-test on subgroups, but what is the most appropriate way to encounter for (continuous) Age and, possibly, other confounders e.g. weight? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could fit a linear regression to the response variable (chemical in blood) with predictors being age, gender and patient group. From the model you get an estimate of the "group" coefficient with associated standard error and p-value for the null hypothesis that "group" does not affect the chemical.

In R the syntax would be something like:

```
   lm1 <- lm(chemical ~ age + gender + group)
   summary(lm1)
```

This is assuming the residuals from the model are normally distributed and other assumptions for linear regression are satisfied.